# Querying csv files like sql

Tags: bash, awk, python, csv

This is apparently a popular interview question:

There are 2 CSV files with dinosaur data. We need to query them to return dinosaurs satisfying a certain condition.

There are 2 choices - use only Unix command-line tools (`cut`/`paste`/`sed`/`awk`), or use a scripting language like Python, but **no additional modules** like `q`, `fsql`, `csvkit` etc.

- file1.csv:

  ```
  NAME,LEG_LENGTH,DIET
  Hadrosaurus,1.2,herbivore
  Struthiomimus,0.92,omnivore
  Velociraptor,1.0,carnivore
  Triceratops,0.87,herbivore
  Euoplocephalus,1.6,herbivore
  Stegosaurus,1.40,herbivore
  Tyrannosaurus Rex,2.5,carnivore
  ```
- file2.csv

  ```
  NAME,STRIDE_LENGTH,STANCE
  Euoplocephalus,1.87,quadrupedal
  Stegosaurus,1.90,quadrupedal
  Tyrannosaurus Rex,5.76,bipedal
  Hadrosaurus,1.4,bipedal
  Deinonychus,1.21,bipedal
  Struthiomimus,1.34,bipedal
  Velociraptor,2.72,bipedal
  ```
- using the forumla:

  ```
  speed = ((STRIDE_LENGTH / LEG_LENGTH) - 1) * SQRT(LEG_LENGTH * g)
  ```

  where

  ```
  g = 9.8 m/s^2
  ```

Write a program to read csv files, and print only names of bipedal dinosaurs, sorted by speed from fastest to slowest.

In SQL, this would be simple:

```
select f2.name from
file1 f1 join file2 f2 on f1.name = f2.name
where f1.stance = 'bipedal'
order by (f2.stride_length/f1.leg_length - 1)*pow(f1.leg_length*9.8,0.5) desc
```

How can this be done in Bash or Python ?

Comment: Just a slight tweak: cut, paste, sed, and awk are *external* to bash, not built in at all. They're available to csh, ksh, zsh, etc., in the same way.

Comment: ... and some (e.g. awk) are also available in non-UNIX environments such as Windows. The difference between python and the other tools you mention is that those other tools come as standard on all POSIX-compliant UNIX installations (and so are generally referred to as standard UNIX tools) while python doesn't. awk and python are both scripting languages.

Comment: "_inbuilt bash tools (cut/paste/sed/awk)_", these are all external tools and nothing to do with `bash`. If you've got `cut`, `paste`, etc. then you've arguably also got `perl` and `python`. They are no more or less inbuilt to `bash`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mention this is an interview question.  If I was asked this on an interview I would be asking questions about the limitations, e.g., why we have them, what is allowed and what isn't, what the reason is.  For each question I'd be trying to make a connection back to why we have the limitations in a business context to really understand what's going on here.

Also, I would ask about the origins of the formula for the speed of the animal, but that's just because my physical science background is stronger than my life science background and I'm curious about it.

As an interviewer, I would really like to hear there are standard tools for CSV parsing.  I would specifically look out to hear that parsing/munging from scratch using scripts or command line utilities is less desirable than using standard tooling like `pandas` and `csv`.

Stack Exchange is not suitable for this type of iterative Q&A, so instead I will just post an answer using Python that I would only provide on an interview after really understanding the business problem.

```
# Assume it's OK to import sqrt, otherwise the spirit of the problem isn't understood.
from math import sqrt

# Read data into dictionary.
dino_dict = dict()
for filename in ['file1.csv','file2.csv']:
    with open(filename) as f:
        # Read the first line as the CSV headers/labels.
        labels = f.readline().strip().split(',')

        # Read the data lines.
        for line in f.readlines():
            values = line.strip().split(',')
        
            # For each line insert the data in the dict.
            for label, value in zip(labels, values):
                if label == "NAME":
                    dino_name = value
                    if dino_name not in dino_dict:
                        dino_dict[dino_name] = dict() # New dino.
                else:
                    dino_dict[dino_name][label] = value # New attribute.

# Calculate speed and insert into dictionary.
for dino_stats in dino_dict.values():
    try:
        stride_length = float(dino_stats['STRIDE_LENGTH'])
        leg_length = float(dino_stats['LEG_LENGTH'])
    except KeyError:
        continue
    
    dino_stats["SPEED"] = ((stride_length / leg_length) - 1) * sqrt(leg_length * 9.8)
    
# Make a list of dinos with their speeds.
bipedal_dinos_with_speed = list()
for dino_name, dino_stats in dino_dict.items():
    if dino_stats.get('STANCE') == 'bipedal':
        if 'SPEED' in dino_stats:
            bipedal_dinos_with_speed.append((dino_name, dino_stats['SPEED']))

# Sort the list by speed and print the dino names.
[dino_name for dino_name, _ in sorted(bipedal_dinos_with_speed, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)]
```

> ['Tyrannosaurus Rex', 'Velociraptor', 'Struthiomimus', 'Hadrosaurus']

Comment: +1 as much for the disquisition as for the python snippet, although I believe that OP wanted `sorted(..., key=... , reverse=True)` in the end.

Comment: Thanks @Cbhihe, I made the change to reflect the requirements.

Comment: Missing some pythonisms here like defaultdict etc, but this is a great answer and definite pass. Honestly, I think the first part is more important than the answer you gave. Tests and code review catch bad code. It's way harder to prevent wasting hundreds of thousands of dollars solving problems no one really needs solved.

Answer (score 5):

Some tools have been created to serve this purpose. Here is example:

```
$ csvq 'select * from cities'
+------------+-------------+----------+
|    name    |  population |  country |
+------------+-------------+----------+
| warsaw     |  1700000    |  poland  |
| ciechanowo |  46000      |  poland  |
| berlin     |  3500000    |  germany |
+------------+-------------+----------+

$ csvq 'insert into cities values("dallas", 1, "america")'
1 record inserted on "C:\\cities.csv".
Commit: file "C:\\cities.csv" is updated.
```

https://github.com/mithrandie/csvq

Comment: yes, tools like fsql, csvkit etc exist but the issue is that such tools/modules by 3rd party devs may not be supported in future, hence not production-ready. also if file size is huge in TBs, it may not work.

Comment: But isn't that true for all tools? And if you have TBs of data, using csv would be the wrong way of storing data anyways.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the great [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and run

```
mlr --csv join -j NAME -f file1.csv \
then put '$speed=($STRIDE_LENGTH/LEG_LENGTH - 1)*pow(($LEG_LENGTH*9.8),0.5)' \
then sort -nr speed \
then cut -f NAME file2.csv
```

to obtain

```
NAME
Tyrannosaurus Rex
Velociraptor
Euoplocephalus
Stegosaurus
Hadrosaurus
Struthiomimus
```

It's a tool you can use in almost every OS and script via bash (and other scripting languages). And it's as cut/paste/sed/awk.

Answer (score 3):

```
#!/bin/bash
awk '
BEGIN { FS=","; OFS="\t" }
NR==FNR { ll[$1]=$2 }
NR!=FNR {
    if ( ($3== "bipedal")  && ($1 in ll) ) {
        speed=($2/ll[$1]-1) * sqrt(ll[$1]*9.8)
        print speed, $1
    }
}
' file1.csv file2.csv | sort -rn | cut -f 2
Tyrannosaurus Rex
Velociraptor
Struthiomimus
Hadrosaurus
```

(untested)
If it is the first file then store the leg length in the ll array

If it is the second file and we have a leg length then calculate the speed and print it out together with the name.

Sort the results numerically then discard all but the name.

Comment: @EdMorton I never mind fixes.

Comment: Good answer. I was torn between accepting this or the Python one.

Answer (score 2):

A g`awk` but doing an initial `join` and then the final sort internally to `awk`

```
join -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) | 
    awk -F, -v g=9.8 '/bipedal/{osaur[$1]=($4/$2-1)*sqrt(g*$2)}
        END{PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@val_num_desc"; for (d in osaur) print d}'

Tyrannosaurus Rex
Velociraptor
Struthiomimus
Hadrosaurus
```

**Edit for @Cbhihe comment**

A useful resource on controlling how `gawk`[scans arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Controlling-Scanning.html).

`PROCINFO["sorted_in"]` can be set to control the sequence in which an array is read.

In this case it is to use the `@val`ues assuming they are `num`eric and sort them `desc`ending, hence `@val_num_desc`.

An array could equally well be output using `@ind`ices assuming they are `str`ings and to sort them `asc`ending in which case it would have been `@ind_str_asc`

Any combination of those flies and all of these are in the linked resource.

Comment: Not familar with **G**awk here. Can you explain the PROCINFO array...? Looks a bit like the ENVIRON array with env-var strings as indexes in good ol' `awk`,  but what on earth is `@val_num-desc`  ;-)

Comment: @Cbhihe updated with a bit of info for you.

Comment: Indeed it is a `gnu` specific thing according to the dox. handy though.

Answer (score 2):

bu5hman's solution is nice and can be made more readable and modifiable by revising it as follows:

```
$ join -t, <(sort file1.csv) <(sort file2.csv) |
awk -F, -v g=9.8 '/bipedal/{osaur[$1]=($4/$2-1)*sqrt(g*$2);
print $1 "=" osaur[$1]; }' | sort -t= -rnk2
```

Result:

```
Tyrannosaurus Rex=6.45447
Velociraptor=5.38445
Struthiomimus=1.37078
Hadrosaurus=0.571548
```

NOTE: pipe the above result to `cut -d= -f1` to show only the names

Comment: I thought it was worth the `PROCINFO` just to get `for (d in osaur)`.....

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that Python is allowed.

This makes it pretty simple because Python includes built in support for sqlite3.
Here is the link to the documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html. All you need to do is create a SQL table for your CSV file using the first row as the column names and insert the data. From there you can run as many select statements as you like.

If you need something to be a number instead of text try scanning the data and check if it's possible to convert each cell to an integer or float and if so you know what its type should be if you can do the conversion for all cells in a column.

Answer (score 1):

Using `csvkit` and ordering by the square of the speed (as SQLite does not have a `sqrt()` or `pow()` function).  Also correcting the given SQL query to use the `stance` from `f2` rather than `f1` (where it's not available).

```
$ csvsql --query "
select f2.name from
file1 f1 join file2 f2 on f1.name = f2.name
where f2.stance = 'bipedal'
order by (f2.stride_length/f1.leg_length - 1)*(f2.stride_length/f1.leg_length - 1)*(f1.leg_length*9.8) desc
" file1.csv file2.csv
NAME
Tyrannosaurus Rex
Velociraptor
Struthiomimus
Hadrosaurus
```